# Rotate a Vector 3D by a small amount

Tags: vector, 3d, rotation

So I have a 3d vector (Javascript + Three.js, but it doesnt really matter, since this is not dependant on language) and I want to rotate it by a small amount in a random direction.
The background is, I want to have a random weapon spread in a 3d shooting game, so I have a vector where  the player is aiming, but need to rotate it slightly in a random direction by a max angle.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute an *offset* vector in the plane defined by your direction (`dir`), add it to `dir` and then normalize to get the new direction.

If you can assume your `dir` vector never points up (assuming *y-up*), you can do something like this (some functions are made-up):

```js
var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

var dir = new THREE.Vector3(...);
dir.normalize();

// Vectors defining the plane orthogonal to 'dir'.
var side = new THREE.Vector3();
var up = new THREE.Vector3();

// This will give a vector orthogonal to 'dir' and 'yAxis'.
side.crossVectors(dir, yAxis);
side.normalize();

// This will give a vector orthogonal both to 'dir' and 'side'.
// This represents the up direction with respect of 'dir'.
up.crossVectors(side, dir);
up.normalize();

// Maximum displacement angle.
var angle = rad(45.0);

// Create a random 2d vector representing the offset in the plane orthogonal
// to 'dir'.
// Alternatively you can draw a random angle 0/2pi and compute sin/cos.
var delta = new THREE.Vector2(rand(-1.0, 1.0), rand(-1.0, 1.0));
delta.normalize();
delta.multiplyScalar(Math.tan(angle));

// 'side' and 'up' define a plane orthogonal to 'dir', so here we're creating
// the 3d version of the offset vector.
side.multiplyScalar(delta.x);
up.multiplyScalar(delta.y);

// Define the new direction by offsetting 'dir' with the 2 vectors in the
// side/up plane.
var newDir = new THREE.Vector3(dir.x, dir.y, dir.z);
newDir.add(side);
newDir.add(up);
newDir.normalize();

// Just check that the angle between 'dir' and 'newDir' is the same as the
// chosen one.
console.log(Math.acos(dir.dot(newDir)) / Math.PI * 180.0);
```

If `dir` can also point up, then you need to generate `side` and `up` using `dir` alone.

Hope this helps.